# How to get the least significant bits of a char in C++

Tags: c++, char

I hava a char variable, and i am only interested in the two least significant hex values. How do I loose al the other values? example:

```
 char input = 0xFFFFFFD1;
```

I want:

```
 output = 0xD1;
```

I tried:

```
output = (input&0x000000FF);
```

but than I just get:

```
output = 0xFFFFFFD1
```

How do i solve this challenge?

Comment: place your code up here!

Comment: A piece of code would be usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that `char` is 8-bit on your platform.  In which case, this:

```
char input = 0xFFFFFFD1;
```

is the same as this:

```
char input = 0xD1;
```

I'm also assuming that `output` is of type `int`.  In which case, you need this:

```
int output = (unsigned char)input & 0xFF;
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/FOdRG.

[*If this is not the problem, then you will need to update your question to include the actual code you're using.*]

Comment: Thanks, making the output an int and input unsigned solved the problem!